# Application Insight TelemetryClient doesn't display logs in Azure Function Console

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I implemented TelemetryClient to sink application logs into Application Insight. Below is my implementation

```
public class Log : ILog
{
    private static TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"] };

    public void Error(string message, Exception ex = null)
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Error);
        if (ex != null)
            telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
    }

    public void Info(string message)
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Information);
    }

    public void Verbose(string message)
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Verbose);
    }

    public void Warning(string message)
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Warning);
    }

    public TelemetryClient TelemetryClient
    {
        get
        {
            return telemetryClient;
        }
    }
}
```

I could see all custom logs in ApplicationInsight

[image]

**Problem** 
When I want to do live monitoring, I could not see custom logs in Azure function  logs window, function display below log which I'm not writing.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide some more details? is it a v1 function app? and where is the ILog from(or which assembly should I reference)? what's your code in the Run() method?

Comment: using v1 function app. ILog is my own interface, which I'm injecting using [Inject] attribute in function app and other places. I want to write unit test with Mock that is why I implemented my own Logger.

Comment: You can refer to jerry's answer below, see if it's the situation.

Comment: not sure how I will resolve ILogger using DI.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected. The Azure function logs window you mentioned shows [logs written in functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#write-logs-in-c-functions) by `TraceWriter` or `ILogger`, including those logs created by function runtime, i.e. the function execution results you saw.

Using this Track* method, telemetryClient sends telemetries for display in Diagnostic Search, which are not available in function log streaming.

If you want see those Track* in function logs, output them using `TraceWriter` or `ILogger`(recommended) and configure log level in [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#configure-logging-in-hostjson).

Comment: Primarily I have Azure function app with multiple layers (service layer, data access layer etc.), where I injected my ILog interface, it helps me to write a unit test with Mock.

Comment: How I can resolve ILogger using Dependency Injection any example?? Azure function will auto resolved when it will trigger, but I'm not sure how I will resolve in other layers.